# AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'LoginView'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am using an older version of django.After i run  my code i get this error -"AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'LoginView'".I should get error if I use login instead of LoginView. Even after using login I get the same attribute error.

this is my urls.py-

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    from . import views

    app_name = 'accounts'

        urlpatterns = [

url(r"login/$",auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"),name='login'),
        url(r"logout/$", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
        url(r"signup/$", views.SignUp.as_view(), name="signup"),
    ]
```

this is my app's urls.py-

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.HomePage.as_view(),name='home'),
    url(r'^accounts/',include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^accounts',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^test/$',views.TestPage.as_view(),name='test'),
    url(r'^thanks/$',views.ThanksPage.as_view(),name='thanks')
]
```

and views.py-

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from . import forms

class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
    template_name = "accounts/signup.html"
```

I got this result after making migrations.My app's name is accounts:-

```
(myDjangoEnv) C:\Users\saini computers\Desktop\simple_social_clone\simplesocial>python manage.py makemigrations accounts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 342, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in _run_checks

    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Git
GitHub
Initialize a new project directory with a Git repository
Create repository
simplesocial\accounts\views.py14:1(13, 372)
LFUTF-8PythonGitHubGit (0)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Desktop\simple_social_clone\simplesocial\simplesocial\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    url(r'^accounts/',include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Desktop\simple_social_clone\simplesocial\accounts\urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    url(r"login/$", auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"),name='login'),
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'LoginView'
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 2):

`LoginView` was added in Django 1.11. If the import fails, you must be using an older version of Django.

Django 1.11 LTS is the oldest supported version of Django, so you really should upgrade, ideally to the latest version 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good idea to say which version you are using. Anyway, the class "LoginView" was implemented in Django 1.11 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)

If your version is compatible with that, try to change the url part to something like:

```
path('accounts/login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='myapp/login.html'))
```

Hope it helps